# Angular 2 ngControl and empty select

Tags: angular

In my app i have select tag create with ngFor loop, and it worked fine until i add ngControl. Now when the page loads there is no default option selected. Why first option isn't used as default?

```
<select  class="form-control icon-caret" name="country" ngControl="country_id">
     <option  *ngFor="let item of countries"  [value]="item.id">
           {{item.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because a control is created in the form model with a default value of `""`

I would expect that you bind the select to the model anyway (how do you get the selected value?). If you set the initial value of the bound property (for example in the constructor) then the item will be selected:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" class="form-control icon-caret" name="country" ngControl="country_id">
     <option  *ngFor="let item of countries"  [value]="item.id">
           {{item.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  selectedCountry;
  countries = [{id: 'USA'}, {id: 'GB'} ];
  constructor() {
    this.selectedCountry = this.countries[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, now it works.  I get values from all form using     `<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formFunc(form.value)">`   is it a good way?